# X-Read report in ax 2012 R3 customization

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I want to customize the X-Read Report in MD AX 2012 R3 which is generated on close shift operation.
The problem is that I do not know Which project or .cs file to be used for its customization in **services solution**.
Please Help!

Comment: Could you add the information how this report is called using the gui?

Comment: @FH-Inway the report is called using Close Shift Operation in AX POS

Comment: I have not worked with POS reports yet, so I may be completely wrong, but what I gather from [Create a POS report](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497829.aspx) is that there does not seem to be a project or .cs file like for SSRS reports. Instead you enter the report definition XML directly in the channel reports configuration. So take a look if you can find your report there.

Comment: @FH-Inway I found it! The report is generated in EOD Project of services solution in retail SDK. However the report in generated using c# code.